# import a file from webserver to mongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

we have a code to upload an image file to a webserver , we used javascript for client side and node js for the server side , the problem given to us is that we have direct the image from the webserver to the mongo DB database and upload the file in mongo DB , the database returns a unique id for each file uploaded , we need to get that unique id.

Comment: Do you have any existing code we can see?

Answer (score 1):

You should **NOT** save image into mongo db. you just need to store a link there assigned to whatever entity collection/document/etc you feel it necessary.

node js has [FS api](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). So use this to store image on disk. and do a link a permalink to it.

hope that make sense.

mondo db driver information [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/)